# How to communicate to BLE module connected to PC serially?

Tags: vb.net, bluetooth, serial-port, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need your help.

Please go through this reference below....

Present status: I made an application which can communicate with PC serial port and this serial port is further connected to BLE module, so that I can send and receive commands and responses through it....

Issue: I have to make a window application (PC program in visual basic only) to scan the nearby Bluetooth devices as a list....and then if I select any one, it would be connected to that device through BLE. 
I am not expert in programming, so looking for your help. Please suggest some code work to implement....

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The enumeration namespace enables you to find devices that are internally connected to the system, externally connected, or detectable over wireless or networking protocols. The APIs that you use to enumerate through the possible devices are the (see. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br225459 ).

```
async void enumerateAvailableDevices() {
  DeviceInformationCollection collection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync();
}
```

Please remember about adding **Capabilities** in **Package.appxmanifest** for bluetooth

Comment: Thanks rudnicki for the suggestion.....I will try this.... 
But so far I tried it in this way. As my BLE module works on AT commands, so I can change its mode to sense the scanning by sending AT-scan commands and receiving the nearby device addresses in my richtextbox. Now I need to select any one device string from richtextbox, while mouse click on it and do some further operation when click on the particular BT address (receiving string) of nearby devices. I am totally new about VB to implement this. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Emlinux

This's piece of code that i've implemented for printer. Hope this will help you figure it out ;)

```
 private string deviceName;
    private string rfCommName;
    private string rfCommId;
    private object rfCommProperty;
    private bool rfCommAvalability;
    private PeerInformation device;
    private HostName hostName;
    private StreamSocket streamSocket = null;
    private DataWriter dataWriter;
    private RfcommDeviceService rfcommService;
    private DeviceInformation deviceInformation;
    private DeviceInformationCollection deviceInformationCollection;
    private static readonly Guid RfcommSerialUuid = Guid.Parse("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private async void searchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:PAIRED"] = "";
        var serviceInfoCollection = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();
        if (serviceInfoCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Search() - There's few paired devices");
            foreach (var peerInfo in serviceInfoCollection)
            {
               if (peerInfo.DisplayName.ToLower().IndexOf("star-") > -1)
               {
                    hostName = peerInfo.HostName;
                    deviceName = peerInfo.DisplayName;
                    device = peerInfo;
                    Debug.WriteLine("Search() - There's your star printer");
                    Debug.WriteLine("Search() - Device - " + deviceName);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Search() - Hostname - " + hostName);
                    textBlock.Text = "I've found ur printer: " + deviceName;
                    break;
               }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Search() - There's no paired devices");
            textBlock.Text = "I didn't found ur printer";
        }
    }

    private async void rfcommButton_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("RfComm() - I'm going to check all Rfcomm devices");
        deviceInformationCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.FromUuid(RfcommSerialUuid)));

        if (deviceInformationCollection != null)
        {
            foreach (var rfComm in deviceInformationCollection)
            {
                if (rfComm.Name.ToLower().IndexOf("star-") > -1)
                {
                    rfCommName = rfComm.Name;
                    rfCommId = rfComm.Id;
                    rfCommProperty = rfComm.Properties;
                    rfCommAvalability = rfComm.IsEnabled;
                    Debug.WriteLine("RfComm() -  name - " + rfCommName);
                    Debug.WriteLine("RfComm() -  id - " + rfCommId);
                    Debug.WriteLine("RfComm() -  property - " + rfCommProperty);
                    Debug.WriteLine("RfComm() -  avalability - " + rfCommAvalability);
                    deviceInformation = rfComm;
                }
            }
        }

        try
        {
            rfcommService = await RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(rfCommId);
            Debug.WriteLine("RfComm() - seems like we're at home");
            textBlock.Text = "seems liek we're at home";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("RfComm() - access to the device is denied");
            textBlock.Text = "access to the device is denied";
        }
    }

    private void socketButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (streamSocket == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Socket() - socket's null");
            lock (this)
            {
                streamSocket = new StreamSocket();
                Debug.WriteLine("Socket() - socket created");
                textBlock.Text = "socket created";
            }
        }

        try
        {
            dataWriter = new DataWriter(streamSocket.OutputStream);
            Debug.WriteLine("Socket() - data writer created");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Socket() - something went wrong while creating writer");
            textBlock.Text = "something went wront while socket creation";
        }
    }

    private async void connectToButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Connect() - Trying to connect");
            await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(hostName, rfcommService.ConnectionServiceName, SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication);
            Debug.WriteLine("Connect() - Connected");
            textBlock.Text = "Connected";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Connect() - Couldn't connect");
            textBlock.Text = "Couldn't connect";
        }
    }
```